# SED update section of file

Tags: awk, sed

Trying to update a settings.py file with new values using SED.

Original section.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

What is should look like.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I've been dabbling with the following, do it it line by line,  but not sure this is the best way. Also my second sed command doesn't seem to work.

```
sed -e 's/sqlite3/mysql/g'  -e 's/'NAME':.*/'myproject'/g'
```

Comment: you cannot use `'` inside `'`, use `\x27` instead... and you'd need to use back-reference or add the `'NAME': ` string manually while replacing... no need for `g` modifier when there is only single replacement

Comment: thanks, so I now have the following. sed -e 's/sqlite3/mysql/g'  -e 's/\x27NAME\x27:.*/\x27NAME\x27:\x20\x27myproject\x27\x2c/g'

Comment: how can I start adding new lines after 'NAME:' I tried the following: sed -e 's/sqlite3/mysql/g'  -e 's/\x27NAME\x27:.*/\x27NAME\x27:\x20\x27myproject\x27\x2c/g' -i '/x27NAME\x27:/a \
line1 \
line2'

Comment: better to add that code to question as edit... it is not clear from comments... for adding new lines, `a` command should do.. or save the lines to be added in a file and use `r` command... use of `\n` and syntax for these commands will depend on your `sed` version... so add that detail to question as well

Comment: More interesting answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303644/how-can-i-use-sed-or-ex-to-replace-a-block-multi-line-code-with-new-block-of-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'function pr(sp, k, v){    # prints key-value pair with indentation
         printf "%s\047%s\047: \047%s\047,\n",sp,k,v; 
     }
     /sqlite/{ sub(/sqlite[0-9]*/,"mysql",$0) }
     /NAME/{ sp=substr($0,1,index($0,"\047")-1); 
             print sp$1" \047myproject\047,"; 
             pr(sp,"USER","myprojectuser"); pr(sp,"PASSWORD","password"); 
             pr(sp,"HOST","localhost"); pr(sp,"PORT",""); next 
     }1' settings.py
```

The output:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject'
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Roman, one comment is the NAME line has no ending comma.

Comment: @Ankh2054, ok, fixed

Answer (score 0):

using sed:

```
sed '/\x27ENGINE\x27: \x27django.db.backends.sqlite3\x27,/!b;N;g;r out' input
```

The contents of the `out` file should be:

```
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'myproject',
    'USER': 'myprojectuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
```

Comment: Does it replace from the line with `ENGINE` till the end of the file?